# Team developing Dynamics CRM 4.0 Customisations

Tags: tfs, dynamics-crm-4

I'm new to CRM and yes, 4.0 is where I'm starting.

I am trying to find out if there is any way to have track and manage changes to CRM Customisations in TFS.

As things stand now I have 3 developers and if 2 devs work on different customisations in the dev crm, when one is ready to be imported into the test environment there is no easy way to separate the changes by different developers.

I can't be the first person to have thought about this but I'm not getting any answers when I google it... I may be wording my question incorrectly but I'm hoping the StackOverflow members can shed some light on this for me.

Comment: Does Dynamics have some way to roll back customizations to a point in time?

Comment: See if http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2013/05/17/release-alm-for-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-crm-solution-lifecycle-management.aspx helps you. Also [dynamics crm and tfs source control](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=dynamics+crm+and+tfs+source+control#q=dynamics+crm+and+tfs+source+control)

Comment: The short answer is that there is no reasonable way to do this in any version of dynamics CRM.

Answer (score 0):

This may be of help to you regarding source control CRM artefacts:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602974.aspx